# Connectivity Issue - RImpala - Kerberos

Tags: r, impala

I'm stuck with Rimpala and Kerberos issue.

All working fine without Kerberos(in laptop Cloudera VM) but my cluster is kerberos enabled and getting below exception

> javax.security.sasl.SaslException:GSS initiate failed 
>   [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any
>   Kerberos tgt)]

Command Used:
rimpala.connect(IP="my-ip",port="port",principal="USERNAME@YOUR-LOCAL-REALM.COM")

I'm providing the principal displayed in klist but still it is unable to connect it.

impala-shell is getting connected and it is getting the detail from credential cache.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others who would face the same issue:

We worked on this issue and found out that the original RImpala didnt have the provision of working with Kerberos. Or it was not working properly. We have fixed the issue and it can be found on github in the URL: https://github.com/selvanponraj/RImpala

Please use the above code and follow the instructions in the README.